# TextBlock gets blured after a 180 degrees PlaneProjection animation

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-8, 3d, rotation

I am doing a 3D rotation in a grid using a `PlaneProjection`:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY" 
                     Storyboard.TargetName="projection" 
                     Duration="0:0:1" To="180" />
</Storyboard>

<Grid.Projection>
    <PlaneProjection x:Name="projection" />
</Grid.Projection>
```

The problem is that at the end of this animation my `TextBlock` gets a little blury like this:

Before Rotation: 
[image]

After Rotation: [image]

Notice that I have already inverted the image. Basicly I do 2 animations (one to 90 degrees) and then I apply a `scaleX` to -1, and then I end the animation.

Already tried some solutions to fix this like the one suggested in [this topic of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719746/silverlight-planeprojection) or even in [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/9d9f2a00-0444-4981-89e9-ced263fd964e).

However, I can't find a way to fix this bug. I belive my solution needs a `PlaneProjection` (or does it?) but in fact I want to rotate two columns of images and text at the same time in oposite directions and PlaneProjection kinda simplifies that approach (since I can rotate a complete Grid). Also, from what I have read this approach uses GPU aceleration :/.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the [UseLayoutRounding](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpfs-most-important-property-uselayoutrounding) Property?

Comment: That option is true by default - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896566(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Another subtle difference to WPF

Comment: I have started with Microsoft Technologies with windows 8 but I am seeing that are many "subtle" differences between windows 8 and wpf :p. Thanks anyways :).